# Bootstrap 3 on Javascript Disabled IE8

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3

After several months of development of an ASP.NET Web Application with Bootstrap 3, css3 & html5, I found out 20% of the 6000+ users in the organization have javascript disabled on browsers for security reasons. For my application to display properly in IE8, I used html5shiv.js and respond.js.

My client's are really very pleased with the interface and layout, but due to the organizations Javascript policy, some browsers are not rendering properly.

Has anyone been in a situation like this? What are the options available? Do I have to redevelop without html5, css3 and bootstrap3? Most of the application depends on modals for some CRUD operations.

Is convincing management against the Javascript policy an option? What references can I use? I'm considering this option because I will be creating more applications for the organization in the near future and most of my applications at the moment are bootstrap, css3 and javascript based. Is this a limitation to me?

Any ideas with useful references will be appreciated. I need to present the application for UAT tomorrow (Friday 1st Aug 2014).

Comment: Tell that organization that they should upgrade their browsers! IE8 is not secure no matter if you disable JavaScript.

Comment: Agreed, and plus Javascript can only be disabled manually. I dont even understand why they would shut it off in the first place.

Comment: These are the sorts of questions you need to ask up-front (and if the answer comes back "yes" and cannot be changed, just walk away)

Comment: @wumm,thanks. That option will be put into consideration, it's bad enough that some users are still on IE7, but we decided it will be too expensive to consider those 5-6% users.

Comment: @Phil, we totally overlooked asking about Javascript, I never assumed for the world of me that any organization would disable javascript. I've learned the hard way. Our usual concern is with IE versions and % of users.

Comment: This actually will help you a lot: http://debeterevormgever.nl/code/html5-elements-ie-without-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a report using the article below from Microsoft to convince management of the need to upgrade their browsers to the latest IE and that did the trick.

http://blogs.windows.com/ie/2012/12/13/ten-reasons-why-internet-explorer-10-is-best-for-business/

I hope this helps someone else. And like Phil said, always remember to include Javascript in your requirements gathering.

Comment: Note: I'm neither affiliated with microsoft nor recommend IE as a browser. I'm only saying item #9 of the article answers my question: "9. Support for modern standards. Modern web applications require support for the latest Web standards. With Internet Explorer 10, we have delivered our most standards-compliant browser ever, including extensive support for industry standards such as HTML5, CSS3, SVG, and ECMAScript5.1."

Comment: Glad this worked to convince management but you should try and find a more recent article. 2012 is ancient in software terms and IE 11 is the latest release (not IE 10)

Comment: @Phil, I agree with you but the date of the article was a plus because it made them look really ancient, one of the challenges they have is the different versions of windows on client machines. They are however considering windows upgrade and IE 11, not 10.